# Facebook api showing warnings with empty page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm adding facebook (facebook javascript api) login to my page and my code is almost empty for testing.

My code is the following:

```
<?php
require_once 'sdk/facebook.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<?php
        // Simplifies parameters
        require("simplify_parameters.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My simplify parameters code:

```
<?php
        // Simplifies parameters

        // Creates app instance
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // I put xxx here as example
          'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ));

        // Gets user id
        $params_login = array("next" => "http://mylink.com/","scope" => "email,publish_stream");
        $params = array("next" => "http://mylink.com/logout.php");
        $fb_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/trick/public_html/index.php:1) in /home/trick/public_html/sdk/facebook.php on line 49

I don't see any call for another session here. There's only one in facebook.php but not any other.

When I take `require("simplify_parameters.php");` off it doesn't show the errors.

Comment: check if you have a space or something before your opening `<?php` in `public_html/index.php`

Comment: @Mark There's no space or something else .. it starts with <?php require_once 'sdk/facebook.php'; ?> Also, if I take require("simplify_parameters.php"); off it doesn't show the errors.

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that something has already been output by the script and you tried to modify the header afterward. Once there has been any output, you are not allowed to modify the headers or start a session. In your case the offending output is on line 1 of index.php. You might have an unintended line break or a space or something that is causing this error.

Comment: I run it normally on my own server.. but when i send it to my webhost it shows those errors!

Comment: @Th3B0Y: That just means you're `php.ini` is different. One has errors enabled, the other doesn't. Ideally you should have the errors enabled on your own server, and off on the live server. (Either that, or you didn't sync your files correctly)

Comment: The problem is when i add the line $fb_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
I don't know what I could do in this case.